# how can use ajax in node js?

Tags: ajax, node.js

i want to use ajax in my node js project , but after runnig the project , i see following error :

```
TypeError: Object function ( w ) {
                if ( !w.document ) {
                    throw new Error( "jQuery requires a window with a document" );
                }
                return factory( w );
            } has no method 'ajax'
```

my code is :

```
                         var jq = require('jquery');
                        jq.ajax({
                              type: "POST",
                              url: "http://localhost/sms/index.php",
                            });
```

Comment: Why would you do this? "use ajax in my nodejs project"? Why not just use regular http requests? `http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback` or one of the wrapper libs?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? 1.x doesn't support non-browser environments.

Comment: @deitch because in http module i must define httpd conf for my php file but i just want to call php file in my localhost. when use http module i get error :  { [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect' }
cd .

Comment: Now I really don't get it. However you make an http connection - `jq.ajax` or `http.request` or whatever - you need some type of server to receive the request and get it back. What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [request module](https://github.com/request/request) (npm install request):

```
var request = require('request');
request({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'http://localhost/sms/index.php',
  json: someJsonObject
  // or form depending on what http://localhost/sms/index.php accepts, 
  // see request document for more options
}, function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body)
  }
});
```

Comment: tnx @Ben , i write below code but in my php file $_POST is empty , what is wrong? var form = {
     number: 'test',
     msg: 'test',
 };

 var formData = querystring.stringify(form);
 var contentLength = formData.length;

 req({
     
     headers: {
       'Content-Length': contentLength,
       'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
     },
     uri: 'http://localhost:8080/send_sms/index.php',
     body: formData,
     method: 'POST'

   }, function (err, res, body) {
      console.log('res is',res);
      console.log('err',err);
   });

Comment: You might need to use 'form' for form data, try form: formData, instead of body: formData. This is from request doc: form - when passed an object or a querystring, this sets body to a querystring representation of value, and adds Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded header. When passed no options, a FormData instance is returned (and is piped to request). See "Forms" section above